# Why do we derive variance-covariance matrix of coefficients instead of variance vector?

Tags: regression, variance, covariance-matrix, intuition

I don't understand why we have to consider covariance.

Is there any problem if I just intuitively understand Var(Y) as variance vector of Y?

Comment: It depends. What do you plan to use that vector for? (I could also decide to round $\pi$ to 3.14 for the same reason ({intuition, simplicity}!). I might even sometimes get away with it. Mostly not, tough.)

Comment: @user603 I'm sorry, the question seems to be a little vague.
While studying homoscedasticity of OLS regression, variance-covariance matrix always comes out and I cannot intuitively understand why we consider the covariance of error terms or even regression coefficients. I think all we need is the variance, not the covariance. I just don't get it intuitively.

Comment: What do you mean by "variance vector?"

Comment: By *variance vector*, do you mean the diagonal of the variance-covariance matrix?

Comment: @MatthewGunn I was thinking about variance vector which has a column of variances of error terms or regression coefficients. 
After I gave that question above, I found out that we need covariance matrix with covariances, not the column matrix of variances because we need to test numerous joint hypotheses.
As far as I know, we need variance of coefficient to get the standard error, which is all about hypothesis testing.

Answer (score 3):

Why do we need covariance matrix? Well, sometimes it is simply not enough to know only variances.  If you by *variance vector* means the diagonal of the covariance matrix, that is,
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{\V}{\mathbb{V}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\v}{\mathbb{v}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Cov}{\mathbb{Cov}}
\v(X) = (\V X_1, \V X_2, \dotsc, \V X_n) = \text{diag}(\V X)
$$
where $\V X$ is the covariance matrix of the random vector $X$, that is,  the $n \times n$ matrix which have for $i,j$-element the covariance between the $i$th ant $j$th elements of the vector $\Cov(X_i,X_j)$. $\v(X)$ is the $n$-vector which have for element $i$ $\V X_i$, the variance of element $i$.

One reason we need this can be seen from the *variance of linear combinations of elements* of $X$. That is given by
$$
\V a^T X = \V \sum_i a_i X_i = \sum_i \sum_j a_i a_j \Cov(X_i,X_j)= \\
    a^T \V(X) a
$$
Look at the 2-vector $X=(X_1, X_2)$ and $\V (X_1 - X_2) = \V X_1 -2 \Cov(X_1,X_2) + \V X_2$.

Suppose $\V X_1 =\V X_2 = 1$ then we can show that $-1 \le \Cov(X_1,X_2) \le 1$ (*).  Using that you can show that $\V(X_1-X_2)$ is somewhere between 0 and 2 only by varying the covariance in the possible range, so indeed it makes a large difference.

(*) You can show this from the fact that the correlation coefficient is between $-1$ and $1$.